# Angular 9 route url changing but view not rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've made a blog app with angular where a component called blog-details containing the details of the blog is rendered on the left side and two other components of called recent blogs and categories are rendered on the right side of the component. Now, when I'm trying to change the blogs by recent blogs, the route URL is changing on the browser but the detailed view of the new blog is not getting rendered on the blog-detail component till I manually refresh the browser. In case you want, you can check my entire Github repository from [here](https://github.com/tridibc2/sample-angular/)

blog-detail.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col bottom">
      <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="currentBlog">
        <h1>{{currentBlog.title}}</h1><hr>
         <div class="img-responsive"><img src="http://localhost/Angular7Blog/api/uploads/{{currentBlog.image}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <hr><br>
         <div [innerHtml]="currentBlog.description"></div>
      </div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 order-2 order-md-2" style="margin-top: 1.1%;">
      <app-recent-blog></app-recent-blog>
      <app-blog-category></app-blog-category>
  </div></div></div>
```

blog-detail.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { BlogpostService } from '../blogpost.service';
import { Blogpost } from '../../models/blogpost';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-detail',
  templateUrl: './blog-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-detail.component.css']})
export class BlogDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   public currentBlog: Blogpost;
     constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private blogpostService: BlogpostService, private titleService: Title) { }
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('blog-detail ngOnInit called')
    let myBlogId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(myBlogId);
    this.blogpostService.getSingleBlogInformation(myBlogId).subscribe(
                (data: Blogpost) =>{ console.log(data); this.currentBlog = data; }
                error =>{ console.log("some error occured");}
```

routing-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RecentBlogComponent } from '../recent-blog/recent-blog.component';
import { BlogCategoryComponent } from '../blog-category/blog-category.component';
import { BlogDetailComponent } from '../blog-detail/blog-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'blog/:id', component: BlogDetailComponent}];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RecentBlogComponent,
    BlogCategoryComponent,
    BlogDetailComponent ],
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule,
    ClientRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
    RecentBlogComponent,
    BlogCategoryComponent,
    BlogDetailComponent
  ]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to update component when url is updated.

In BlogDetialsComponnt you need to change ngOnInit implementation.

add import switchMap:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

ngOnInit should be like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const currentBlog = this.route.params.pipe(
    switchMap(params => {
      this.blogpostService.getSingleBlogInformation(params[id]);
    })
  )
}
```

now `currentBlog` will be updated every time router `id` param is updated

Your example is displaying changes after page refresh because component knows only first id, and every further update is ignored. So after page refresh, component is initiated with new id.

Answer (score 0):

Have to use the `AsyncPipe` in the HTML template to subscribe to an Observable and return the latest value it has emitted and also `switchMap` in the component code to send a new request each time as the param changes

`<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="currentBlog$ | async as blog">`

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

public currentBlog$: Observable<any>    //take currentBlog value as an Observable

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,private blogpostService: BlogpostService,private titleService: Title) {}

ngOnInit() {
let myBlogId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('blogId');
this.currentBlog$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
                    this.blogpostService.getSingleBlogInformation(params['blogId'])));}
```